# How to save multiple canvas content of a division to a png image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Good afternoon,

I have multiple canvas in a main division in following hirarchy:

```
<div id="main">
  <canvas id="one">
  <canvas id="two">
  <div id="main_2">

     <canvas id="three">

  </div>

</div>
```

I am drawing an image inside main division, I want to export all content inside main division and save it as an image, kindly help.

Comment: can you just paste the JS that you have so far?

Comment: Here is the link of my work so far, http://jandeccpl.info/woodensigns/wPaint-master/

Comment: I am unable to save my drawing as an image, kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You have to get canvas data and send it to php server, There you can save it as image!

Get data and send via ajax,

```
var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'save.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(canvasData);
```

PHP,

```
<?php 
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // Get the data
    $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];


    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    $random_digit=md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    $fp = fopen( 'yourfolder/new'.$random_digit.'.png', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

The image will be saved at "yourfolder/new'.$random_digit.'.png'". Link to same question,

[Sending photo from javascript to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018307/sending-photo-from-javascript-to-server/14018570#14018570)