# Is there any way to send image from canvas like binary file in postman?

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-canvas

I want to send an image from canvas to the server. When I send an image from postman it works. But I don't know how to send that image from canvas (HTML5). 
Could u help me with that? I have tried a lot of ways.

The format from the server (it's in case if I send an image from postman)
[click to see format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCA9N.png)

And 
[how I use postman to send an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ZoZ.png)

> ```
> canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 95, 95, 310, 310, 0, 0, 350, 350);
> const request_image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
> $.post({
>     url: 'http://localhost:8088/',
>     data: request_image,
>     success: function (res) {
>         console.log(123);
>         console.log(res);
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> its example how I tried to send that image.
>   In this case server throws `InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with 'data:image/png;b'`

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018307/sending-photo-from-javascript-to-server/14018570

Comment: @little_monkey I have added example how I tried to send.